# Show that if d is an integer such that d|n + 7 and d|n^2 + 3, then d|52

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

any multiple or addition/subtraction d divides will also divide d

So I tried doing d|n+ 7 and d|n^2 + 3.

-> d| (n + 7)^2

= d| n^2 + 14n + 49

then if we add n^2 + 3, we get: n^4 + 14n + 52, which therefore proves that d|52.

Unsure if this is the right way to prove this or how to structure it.

Comment: The last step is not true.

Comment: Why $d\mid n^4+14n+52$ implies that $d\mid 52$?

Comment: $n\equiv-7\pmod d$ and $n^2\equiv-3\pmod d$. So $(-7)^2\equiv-3\pmod d$ etc.

Comment: $n^2 + 14n + 49 + n^2 + 3$ = $2n^2 + 14n + 52$.

Comment: $d$ divides $2n(n+7) + 52$. That means for some integer k, $dk - 2n(n+7) = 52$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: The last step makes not sense.  $(n^2 + 14n + 49) +(n^2 + 3) \ne n^4 + 14n + 52$ it is $2n^2 + 14n + 49$, but *why* would $(n^2 + 14n + 49) +(n^2 + 3) = n^4 + 14n + 52$ prove $d|52$??  It'd prove $d|n^4 + 14n + 52$ and it does divide $2n^2 + 14n + 52$ but that doesn't prove $d|52$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d|n+ 7$ so $

$d|(n+ 7)^2 = n^2 + 14n + 49$.

And adding And $d|n^2 + 3$ so

$d|(n+7)^2 + (n^2 + 3) = 2n^2 + 14n + 52$.

And $d|n+7$ so $d|(n+7)2n = 2n^2 + 14n$.

So $d|(n+7)^2 + (n^2+3) - (n+7)2n  = (2n^2 + 14n + 52)-(2n^2 + 14n) = 52$.

....

It might be more convient to use $\pmod d$ notation:

$n+7 \equiv 0 \pmod d$

$n^2 + 3 \equiv 0 \pmod d$

So $(n+7)^2 \equiv n^2 + 14n + 49 \equiv 0$

And $(n^2 + 14n + 49) + (n^3 + 3)=2n^2 + 14n + 52 \equiv 0$

And $(2n^2 + 14n + 52)-2n(n+7) = 52 \equiv 0 \pmod d$.

......

Or you can go primitive...

There is an integer $k$ so that $kd = n+7$ so $n=kd-7$

And there is an integer $j$ so that $jd = n^2 + 3=(kd-7)^2+3 = k^2d^2 - 14kd + 52$

So $jd - k^2d^2 +14kd = d(j-k^2d + 14k) = 52$

And as $j-k^2d + 14k$ is an integer $d|52$.

Answer (score 2):

$d|n+7\implies d|(n+7)(n-7)=n^2-49$.

If $d|n^2+3$ and $d|n^2-49$, then $d|52$.

Answer (score 1):

Better way

Let $md=n+7\iff n=?$

$n^2+3=(md-7)^2+3=d(m^2d-14m)+49+3$

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ divides $n+7$ it also divides $(n+7)^2 = n^2+14n+49$.

If $d$ divides $n^2+14n+49$ and $n^2+3$, then it also divides $n^2+14n+49-(n^2+3) = 14n+46$.

If $d$ divides $14n+46$ and $n+7$, it also divides $14(n+7) - (14n+46) = 52$.